# ffmpeg による jpg から WebP への変換で結果に差違が出るのはなぜか？

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegで画像をjpgからwebpに変換しました。

**パターン1**
jpgから直接webpに変換

```
-vf scale=1200:-1 -vcodec libwebp -compression_level 6 -qscale 10
```

**パターン2**
jpgをリサイズする

```
-vf scale=1200:-1
```

出力されたjpgをwebpに変換

```
-vcodec libwebp -compression_level 6 -qscale 10
```

パターン1とパターン2で結果が変わるのは何故でしょうか？
1文でパターン2の結果を出力するにはどのように書けばいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

[JPEG](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)は一般的に非可逆圧縮を行います。つまり、`-vf scale=1200:-1`で保存する際に劣化します。

> 1文でパターン2の結果を出力するにはどのように書けばいいでしょうか？

不可能です。パターン1では劣化が発生せずにwebpエンコードされます。

なお、パターン2でPNG形式で保存すると…可逆圧縮されるため劣化は抑えられます。しかし、色空間がJPEGではYCbCrなのに対しPNGはRGBのため、色が変化します。